# Create object names though "for loop" enumeration?

Tags: for-loop, uiimage, enumerate

I'd like to use the increasing integer in a "for loop" to create 5 UIImages with custom names (e.g. UIImage *image1, *image2, etc.). I've named my images programmatically - "foto1.jpg", "foto2.jpg", etc., so I'd also like to load those in also using the integer in the same "for loop"... but I don't know how to replace THAT NUMBER in a title! Like, in the UIImage's name AND when calling up the name of an image. How does one do this?? I've tried this: [NSString: @"foto%d.jpg", i] without success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm a newbie :(
Thank you,
Sebastian

Answer (score -1):

Try this: 
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"foto%d.jpg", i]